# How to update probabality of one option with result of multiple options

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, python

I am working with API that provides only a limited number of results 400 to be exact but I want to gather all of these results.

I can filter results by:

- Predefined price ranges (e.g ['10\$-100\$', '100\$-500\$'])
- Categories - it is possible to specify multiple categories at once (e.g 'cookies' or 'cakes')

Currently, my approach looks something like that:

```py
categories = ['cookies','cakes','meat','vegatables']
for price in price_range:
    query(price,categories)

def query(price_range, categories):
    result = request(price_range, categories)
    if len(request) > 400:
        half = len(categories) // 2
        return [*query(price_range, categories[0:half]),*query(price_range, categories[half:0]))
    return result
```

My algorithm currently is quite naive, because it could split categories from a query for 'nice cake' into `cookies or cakes or cupcakes` and `meat and vegetables`.
That would execute like that:

- Query `meat and vegetables` -> 50 results
- Query `cookies or cakes or cupcakes` -> 600 results so we split

  - Query `cookies` -> 100 results
  - Query `cakes or cupcakes` -> 300 results

So the better split would be `cookies or meat or cupcakes` and `cakes or vegetables`

I've got an idea to track the distribution of the result to make more intelligent splits.

But I ran into the problem of how to update the probability of cakes or cupcakes separately only knowing the data provided by the example above.

**My idea**

I assume that I track the number of things in the category seen and start with one seen in every category.

```py
cookies = 10,
cakes = 15,
meat = 3,
vegetables = 2


cakes = cakes + (number of cakes or cupcakes) * (cakes / (cakes + cookies))
cookies = cookies + (number of cakes or cookies) * (cookies / (cakes + cookies))

meat = meat + (number of meat and vegetables) * (meat / (meat + vegetables))
vegetables = vegetables + (number of meat and vegetables) * (vegetables / (meat + vegetables))
```

Is there any way to improve on this?

Thanks for the answers in advance have a great day :)